# Bringing cash into the USA

Tags: air-travel, usa, money

For a First time immigrant travelling to the United States, Is there a limit in bringing in cash? I understand that when travelling to the U.S., you are only allowed to bring in  a Limit of $10,000.00. Also if you are a family of four or a couple, is it $10.000 for the whole family or $10.000.00 for a couple?

Comment: The "limit" is the amount that you can bring without declaring it. You can bring more but you need to declare how much money you have during the immigration & customs processing upon arrival if it is more than 10K.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a "second time" immigrant?  One would think immigrating is a one time affair ;-)

Comment: @Tom I've changed my country of residence nearly a dozen times, which at the very least required completely re-setting up in the UK twice, so it's not always once ;)

Comment: I'm interested to hear about countries who distinguish between first, second, third time and other immigrants.

Comment: @MarkMayo - guess your definition is different than mine.  For me an immigrant is someone moving permanently to a different country, you on the other are a resident who can't make up their mind ;-)

Comment: Hmm... It seems a bit odd that this question was closed as off-topic to me, as it seems to be more directly related to the act of traveling to the U.S. than to the act of immigrating. That being said, it might be a dupe of [Maximum cash allowed when travelling to the U.S.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/24659/12011). I didn't see an answer directly to the part about whether the limit is individual or per family in the answers, but it is answered by the links in the answers there (it is per family.)

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely risky to bring large amounts of cash to the USA. Especially so (sorry) if you are not white. Meet [civil asset forfeiture](https://www.aclu.org/issues/criminal-law-reform/reforming-police-practices/asset-forfeiture-abuse). If law enforcement does this they will sue your money instead of yourself and it'll be incredibly difficult to get your money back.

If at all possible use a bank wire -- and in one go, otherwise they might snare you for structuring...

Comment: What does a new immigrant coming to the USA have to do with police seizing assets of people suspected of involvement in crimes?

Comment: This happens at [airports](http://dailysignal.com/2015/06/17/law-enforcement-seizes-11000-from-24-year-old-at-airport-without-charging-him-with-a-crime/) just as well. It's not immigration specific.

Comment: @Tom Unfortunately, the police tend to take the position that large amounts of cash are are criminal in nature.  Wire it.

Comment: Good advice but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The rather remote possibility of forfeiture abuse aside, the possibility of theft (by TSA or anyone near your bags) is a much more probable reason why you should avoid carrying huge amounts of cash with you (in any part of the world, at an airport or otherwise.)