# USA, travelling with more than USD 10,000

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, money

I will be leaving for USA in a little while, and I plan to carry around USD 12,500. I will be visiting my son there, and I will hand over that cash to him then.

As I understand, if the amount is more than USD 10,000 you must declare it, using [this form](https://www.fincen.gov/forms/files/fin105_cmir.pdf).

However, it states

> Each person who receives currency or other monetary instruments in the
>   United States shall file FinCEN Form 105, within 15 days after receipt
>   of the currency or monetary instruments, with the Customs officer in
>   charge at any port of entry or departure or **by mail with the
>   Commissioner of Customs, Attention: Currency Transportation Reports,
>   Washington DC 20229.**

After I have handed the money over to my son, will my son need to declare it? Also, what other documentation would I be needing if the cash exceeds USD 10,000?

I have already searched through [this link](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24659/maximum-cash-allowed-when-travelling-to-the-us?newreg=2cbfec9aedd347ab9f348c6cc452be8b), and haven't found what I am looking for.

Comment: I believe so. And if your son uses a bank, they will report his large cash deposit.

Comment: Is your son carrying it in or out of the US?

Comment: If you get any further questions, it will be very useful if you have documentation that indicates the source of the cash and can demonstrate that it comes from legal activities.

Comment: I've needed to transfer rather larger sums of money into the USA, and used electronic funds transfer. Have you considered doing that?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes, i tried doing, thrice, and my wire was rejected thrice. Since I am going anyways, i thought i should ask if taking the bany by hand would be legal :)

Comment: Why dont you just issue a check, if you are wire transfers are not going through. You can also carry the check rather than cash!

Comment: "my wire was rejected thrice" that doesn't make much sense.  Do you mind saying what country you are sending the wire from?

Comment: @pbu Checks need to be declared too so that doesn't really change anything.

Comment: @Relaxed checks need only be declared if they can be cashed by the bearer. If he brought a check made payable to his son he would not need to declare it, if my quick reading of [the rules](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/332/kw/332/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNTE0NjYyMDk3L3NpZC8xeG9SRndCbg%3D%3D) is correct.  (The declaration would be made when the check is negotiated in such a case.)

Comment: @Fattie "Thrice" is like "twice", but meaning three times.  His wire transfer failed three times.

Comment: howdy @JimMacKenzie, right I know what "thrice" means :)  My point was, it makes little sense it was "rejected", especially three times.  In the rare cases a wift transfer is rejected, it's just a problem in one of the numbers, and they just ask you to correct it.

Comment: Unless it involves a country or person of concern.  Is this a payment for one good/service, or a clumped payment for several?  Because don't smurf (split a payment for one thing into several separate payments) but don't countersmurf either (combining several separate payments for ordinary things into a superpayment which attracts attention).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form instructions state that the declaration only needs to be made once. You don't need to do it twice.

> An additional report of a particular transportation, mailing, or shipping of currency or the monetary instruments is not required if a complete and truthful report has already been filed.

Your son does not need to file a report anyway, since he is not the person importing the currency or causing it to be imported. You are importing the currency, so you will file the declaration.

Comment: "Your son does not need to file a report anyway, since he is not the person importing the currency or causing it to be imported": paragraph b under "who must file" says recipients must file, and makes no mention of whether they've caused the currency to be imported. The only basis for not filing as far as I can see is the passage you have quoted.  If the son were to receive the money without knowing whether the father had filed, he would need to file.

Comment: @phoog He may be receiving currency, but he is _not_ importing it. That is the important part. Nothing here is relevant to someone who isn't importing or exporting currency or instruments. If he had had it shipped to him by FedEx or something, then he would be the importer and the recipient in this context.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. See my answer

Comment: @Hilmar You haven't posted an answer!

Comment: @MichaelHampton you can't ship currency or currency instruments using FedEx

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I did post answer. Could have been delayed by a few minutes. I interpret the instructions in the form as "both must file". The person who brings it AND the person who receives it.

Comment: @Hilmar You appear to have waited almost 20 minutes after notifying me, to post your answer. You also seem to be interpreting this contrary to the plain meaning of the instructions (and the intent of the law).

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think you are conflating two different situations: filing at the time of entry into the US (for physically transported money); and filing for receipt of money transported from outside the US by the recipient. By the plain meaning of the instructions, the report must always be filed at the border by someone transporting it across. Given that, by what you say, item (2) under Who Must File would _never_ be triggered by money being "transported" to them, yet the word plainly appears in there as a trigger. Transported cannot be shipped or mailed, since those are separately listed.

Comment: The recipient is the beneficiary of the money being imported. It's not as if the money is being imported by a US resident, put into circulation, and then the same amount is later given to the recipient with other physical currency. I feel you would have a hard time convincing a judge that given these facts, the son is not a recipient within the meaning of item (2). The question then becomes does the other section you quoted (regarding an "additional report") apply. That, I believe, is far more open to interpretation.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid sure you can.  Their rules may forbid it, but that doesn't stop someone from putting a bunch of cash in an envelope and shipping it by FedEx.

Comment: @phoog you do know they screen for this stuff, right? You will also put the recipient in a hell of trouble the package is scanned.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid in trouble with whom?  With FedEx?

Comment: Does he have to fill the report on both airports?

Answer (score 11):

Travelling in the United States with such a huge amount of cash is extremely dangerous because civil forfeiture. Your money can be taken at the [airport](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2015/06/30/drug-cops-took-a-college-kids-life-savings-and-now-13-police-departments-want-a-cut/), by the [security at the airport](http://theantimedia.org/tsa-seizes-75000-in-cash-from-passenger-for-zero-reason/) a [routine traffic stop](http://america.aljazeera.com/watch/shows/america-tonight/articles/2015/7/28/civil-forfeiture-new-mexico-conviction-money-property.html) and practically anywhere else. Once the cops seize the cash they will not charge you (often they won't have anything to charge you with) but the *money* itself and you will have a lot of difficulties getting it back.

Comment: Carrying cash is inherently risky.  Is there any evidence that the risk of legal seizure is significantly higher than other inherent risks (loss, accidental destruction, theft)?  If not, it seems excessive to call out this specific risk among others. (And after all, at least in principle, money seized in this way can be recovered by legal means, unlike cash accidentally destroyed or stolen).

Comment: I'd say most people are acutely aware of such problems and will prepare accordingly -- money belt etc but this is a much more obscure (especially for someone not living in the US) danger.

Comment: I would be curious to see statistics on this "extremely dangerous" action.  How many travelers (what percentage) have been effected by this? Isolated incidents do not equate to a risk factor, rather they only contribute to paranoia.

Comment: First you'd need statistics on how many people carry significant amounts of cash. I think this would be hard to acquire. Then you'd need to find the number of cash seizures and since many government agencies can seize cash this will be very difficult as well. As far as I am concerned, one is too many. I am very careful to only carry <20USD with me when I go through an USA airport.

Comment: Being careful to have less that $20 on you when going through a US airport is an act of paranoia. All three stories you link to involve people carrying unusually large amounts of cash, which is what sparked suspicion. That's highly relevant to this question but there is zero reason for anybody to worry about carrying a couple-few hundred dollars in cash through an American airport.

Comment: Carrying less than $20 USD when going through a USA airport is the most risky behavior. You never know when an airline will lose your luggages, or delay you by a day or two, or charge you $10 USD for a small bag of peanuts (that used to be given out for free). And yes, credit cards will work in most cases, but cash still reigns supreme when the infrastructure is down because of a blizzard, or if your credit card got temporarily deactivated because your bank thinks you were acting suspicious by traveling to a different country.

Comment: With large amounts of cash, there is a HUGE risk of civil forfeiture when moving around or in or out of the US.  It's the only major nation where this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

If you send the money by a bank wire to your son, then the banks will file the proper notification paperwork at both ends.

If you carry it into the country in cash, then you need to declare that fact and fill out FinCEN Form 105 for your trip, as you have noted. But you are not "importing" it rather you are "carrying" it in. - https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/195/kw/more%20than%20$10000%20cash/

The "receiving person" details mentioned in your post would apply if you sent the money by courier or other means where the responsible party is not physically moving the money.  It also applies to bank wires, but the banks usually handle the declaration paperwork for their customers automatically.

There maybe restrictions or declarations in your country of origin to consider as well.

If your son deposits it into his US bank account, then the bank will have to declare that deposit as it is over $10K.  But that again is paperwork the bank will handle automatically, with perhaps a few questions for your son.

Comment: Large gifts are taxable to the donor (!), not the recipient. https://www.irs.gov/uac/Eight-Tips-to-Determine-if-Your-Gift-is-Taxable

Comment: Answer edited.  But ultimately, we don't know what the money is for (gift, loan, living expenses, etc) or what its source is (wages for remote work, dad's bank account, etc).

Answer (score 3):

I would be very careful in the United States with cash, due to Asset Forfeiture.

It's hard to say how high the risk or frequency, but there seem to be many incidents of this occurring.  Of the cases I have followed where there is no justifiable cause, most have been unable to get any of their money back even after long legal processes.  In some cases the asset owner has been able to negotiate return of a small percentage.

The frequency seems to be higher with local law enforcement, but also exists with state and federal.  These cases are kept quiet and charges are rarely levied.

Answer (score 3):

If this is useful, I've entered the USA twice with way more than $10,000 in traveler checks (but not in cash). The procedure is the following: you mark it on the Custom declaration, go to Customs, they check your declaration and send you to the secondary desk. There you are given a simple form, fill it up and give it to them. After that you're done. They didn't ask to see the traveler checks or count them, and generally looked completely uninterested and unexcited about the whole process.

No unusual questions were asked by the Customs, but my bank (where I deposited it), asked whether I declared it to the Customs. I said "yes" and they didn't have any further questions.

Answer (score 2):

> WHO MUST FILE: (1) Each person who physically transports, mails, or
> ships, or causes to be physically transported, mailed, or shipped
> currency or other monetary instruments in an aggregate amount
> exceeding $10,000 at one time from the United States to any place
> outside the United States or into the United States from any place
> outside the United States, and
>
> (2) Each person who receives in the
> United States currency or other monetary instruments In an aggregate
> amount exceeding $10,000 at one time which have been transported,
> mailed, or shipped to the person from any place outside the United
> States.

It looks like you both must file since the last word in the first paragraph is "and". While it is perfectly legal and can attract a lot of undesirable attention from the authorities such as the IRS or the department of homeland security. We did this once as a young white couple with three small children in tow and still got subjected to intense questioning.

First: I would NOT use cash because of risk of loss and high currency exchange fee. If you need a cash-like instrument, use travelers checks. These can be replaced if stolen and typically just have a 1% flat fee. They still are subject to declaration.

Electronic transfers are safer, cheaper, and easier on the paperwork. I use http://www.xe.com/xetrade/ to send money to kids abroad. Many banks these days have direct partnerships with other banks in different countries for mutual use of ATMs and low overhead transfer. For example Bank of America works with Deutsche Bank in Germany, Santander in Mexico, China Construction Bank, Westpac in Australia/NZ etc.  I recommend talking to your local bank or finding a Bank in your country with ties to the US.

Comment: I agree with you regarding who must file - the instructions clearly indicate both the person physically transporting it and the recipient must file. The question, I believe, is whether two reports have to be filed based on the subsequent statement about an "additional report" being unnecessary if one was already filed for a "particular transportation" - does the filing for transport across the border suffice to cover the recipient receiving it too? Or are those two separate incidents under the regulations?

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this because of "J Bergen"s poor answer.  Bergen gives some bad advice.

1. You can bring as much currency into the country as you want, as long as you declare it.  Otherwise, there will be penalties

   NEVER STRUCTURE YOUR MONEY: i.e. bring in amounts under $10,000 multiple times.  That's as bad as not declaring, and could see your visa revoked.

   Western Union is not good

   If you are unsure if the total amount of money (in any currency) you have anywhere (in your bags, pockets, shoe, etc) is equivalent to US$10,000 or more, DECLARE

Answer (score 0):

The USA is a country with an effective, reliable banking system that does a good job serving consumers with virtually no graft or theft. As such, the only people who handle large quantities of cash are:

- fools
- criminals

This may differ dramatically from your country.  The US government is primarily concerned with the second, and cares less about the property rights of the first.  "A fool and his money..."

So it may be standard practice in your country to deal in cash, but in America it will get a frosty reception because of these prejudices. With an underlying assumption that more likely than not, it is in America's best interests to separate you from your money. There will be a mechanism by which you can appeal for its return, but this could cost a big chunk of $12,500 in lawyer costs.

The way America expects you to do this is via the trusted, western banking system.  For instance have your friend generate an invoice on PayPal for the goods or services, and pay them via PayPal.  **If for some reason you can't do conventional electronic transfers, you need to fix why that is**.

Bringing in cash because electronic transfers don't work is just the kind of thing they're on guard for. Customs will know the reasons your wire transfers were disallowed, and will be wary of cash moving on the same route.  Effectively you're circumventing the normal way of doing this.

That isn't [structuring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuring), but they have a lot in common.

The upshot is that bringing large blocks of cash is a fool's game, and you should expect problems.

Answer (score -4):

Don't do it!  Also check how much the Country you are going to allows you to come in with!  It is a scam in many places.  America allows you $10,000 do not be a penney over that amount even in change or they will steal it from you! Or tie you up so you miss your flight.  Some Countries do to exchange rate allow a little less than that. So on arrival they will steal it from you! As you are over there amount to bring in. 3rd world Countries are good for this scam!  Set up a Western Union acount & wire yourself the money to were ever. If they have Western Union there. Then bring in $6,000 at a time on 2 transfers.

Comment: You can bring as much money into the US as you want, you just have to declare it.  If you don't declare it, you get penalized, with a penalty of from $250 to complete forfeiture, depending on whether you have documentation for the money or not.  If you declare it, they have you sign a form, and you're good