# How much money can an Indian tourist carry to London

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, money

How much money can an Indian tourist carry to London. Is there a regulation by the Indian government or Uk Govt.

Comment: Are you asking how much you/one should carry or maximum amount you/one can carry?

Answer (score 9):

There is no limit for bringing money into the UK, however amounts of 10000 euro must be declared:

e.g. from the [VisitLondon site](http://www.visitlondon.com/traveller-information/travel-to-london/customs-and-visas/uk-customs-allowances#3Ls9DUvkrJvLsY5A.97):

> Declaring Your Goods   When entering the UK from a non-EU country, you
>   must make a declaration to customs if:
>
> You have 10,000 euros or more (or equivalent) in cash

The amount you can take out of India is covered thoroughly in this question:

[How much cash can I carry while travelling from India to Poland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24153/how-much-cash-can-i-carry-while-travelling-from-india-to-poland)